# When I do "makemigrations" I get do "makemigrations"

Tags: python, django, model, migration, django-orm

I removed all migration files from my django project and now when i want to re-create i get this

```
 ./manage.py makemigrations
 INFO: AXES: BEGIN LOG :: [axes.apps] 2022-09-15 16:51:59,923 - 
 /home/mixnosha/work_MVD/MVD_LTP/MVD_LTP-ltp/venv/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/axes/apps.py:33
 INFO: AXES: Using django-axes version 5.31.0 :: [axes.apps] 2022-09-15 16:51:59,926 
 - /home/mixnosha/work_MVD/MVD_LTP/MVD_LTP-ltp/venv/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/axes/apps.py:34
 INFO: AXES: blocking by IP only. :: [axes.apps] 2022-09-15 16:51:59,927 - 
 /home/mixnosha/work_MVD/MVD_LTP/MVD_LTP-ltp/venv/lib/python3.10/site- 
 packages/axes/apps.py:46
 No changes detected

./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, axes, base_information, contenttypes, 
django_celery_beat, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
Your models in app(s): 'admin', 'auth', 'axes', 'contenttypes', 'sessions' have 
changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py 
migrate' to apply them.
```

Recommend something

Comment: Try explicitly saying what app. `python manage.py makemigrations {app}`

Comment: Have you gone through all of your apps and removed all of the previous `.pyc` files from `/migrations/_pycache_/ `?

Comment: i tried this `python manage.py makemigrations {app}` but then i do `manage.py migrate`  and  i get `raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration members.0001_initial is applied before its dependency company_directory.0002_initial on database 'default'.
`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you still have a migrations folder in each app with an `__init__.py` file?

Edit: Looks like this was the accepted answer. To anyone who stumbles across this: Without an `__init__.py` file django will not recognize the migrations folder. Creating an `__init__.py` file will solve this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).